# For which $n\in \mathbb N$ does $n^n$ end with a $3$ in its decimal form?

Tags: number-theory

> For which $n\in \mathbb N$ does $n^n$ end with a $3$ in its decimal
>   form?

I didn't really know where to go from here, but I thought I might be able to use that
$n^n \equiv 3 \text{ (mod } 10)$ , $n^n \equiv 3 \text{ (mod } 5)$ and $n^n \equiv 1 \text{ (mod } 2)$. Since the $gcd(2,5)=1$ I thought I might be able to do something with the Chinese remainder theorem, but so far I'm not sure how.

I'd prefer a hint over a full answer :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $n=10(2m+1)+3$ works for $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$ ; remains to check if this is the solution or if still other exist

Comment: @user90369 $n=7$ is one of the solutions I found, and you can't get $n=7$ with your formula.

Comment: You are right. We also can use $n=10(2m+1)-3$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct : if $k \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $k \equiv 3 \mod 5$ then $k \equiv 3 \mod 10$ must happen by CRT.

Therefore, it is sufficient to find $n$ such that $n^n \equiv 3 \mod 5$ and is odd. Of course, $n^n$ is odd if and only if $n$ is odd.

Additionally, $n^n$ now breaks into cases when we go into five. If $5$ divides $n$, of course $n^n$ can't end with $3$. Therefore, $n$ cannot be a multiple of $5$. Then, $n^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$, by Fermat's theorem. Therefore, let $n \equiv k \mod 4$, $0 \leq k \leq 3$, then $n^n \equiv n^k \mod 5$. Finally, if $n \equiv l \mod 5$ then $n^n \equiv n^k \equiv l^k \mod 5$ ,where $0 \leq l < 5$. Now, there are not too many cases to check : only $k = 1$ or $3$ and $l = 1,2,3,4$ are to be checked. Can you finish?

Comment: Breaking it into $k$ and $l$ is of course _correct_, but it seems to me that it would be easier to say that $n^n$ modulo $5$ must repeat with a period of $\operatorname{lcm}(5,\varphi(5)) = 20$ -- so we need to check the odd numbers between $0$ and $20$ that are not multiples of $5$. (These are the same as the ones you say to check, but one doesn't need to figure out which of them correspond to which $l,k$).

Comment: Ah yes, that is also true.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry, but I don't understand why $n^n$ mod 5 must repeat with a period of $lcm(5,\varphi(5))$. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Noah_K: By modular arithmetic and Euler's theorem we have $$ n^n \equiv (n\bmod 5)^{n\bmod\varphi(5)} \pmod 5 $$ If you increase $n$ by any common multiple of $5$ and $\varphi(5)$, neither $n\bmod 5$ nor $n\bmod\varphi(5)$ will change.